# Naming mixin which is used as service (api call)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, mixins

Generally my naming convention for mixin is feature_mixin.js

However, for some classes (which are used to make api service calls), i have the naming as feature_service.js (Even though I use the above as Mixin)

Now since, Ember has a separate Service class concept, Is there a better naming convention for such kind of mixins ?

Answer (score 0):

I can just share my own approach. All mixins I'm saving in app/mixins dir with names, for example, *pagination.js*, *remember-scroll*. Without any suffixes. Import string looks next:

```
import PaginationMixin from '../mixins/pagination';
```

All services I stored in app/services. Also without any suffixes in names. It is a structure that [ember-cli](http://ember-cli.com/) provides.

In addition I can recommend you to think about transfering logic from some of your mixins to new services.

Comment: I suggest using the `'<app-name>/mixins/pagination'` style of paths so that you can more easily move the service around and not have it break.